# Local SQL Server 2005 database connection throwing exception

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I have a local database in my machine in SQL Server 2005. When I tried to connect to the database with the `system` user I am getting an exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):` Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.

Could you please help?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     string connectionString = "server = (local); database = XXXXX;trusted_connection=yes";

     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
     {
          connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
          connection.Open();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Give access to login 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' on your database ,go to sql mngt studio >Logins ,right click 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' ,select properties.
2. Put Integrated Security=SSPI in your connection string.

[image]